# objective c Push notification BackGround remove old one when receive new one in Notification center

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter, appdelegate

I created a application. That receives push notifications from server.
This all works for me. 
But the only thing is that i want that my old push notification in notification center will be removed when i receive a new one.
What do i need to do in this function
`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary *)userInfo {`

This doesn't solve my problem
   `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];` 
doesn't work

It is for Background(when you are home screen or locked your phone).

Or is it possible to replace your old push notification for new one

Comment: ohhh.....as per my knowledge not possible if you your app in backgroud/not running, there is no way to way to accomplish this.

Comment: changing badge to zero should remove all notifications from center. Otherwise there is no other way.